# Determining size of a JSON document stored in DocumentDB

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm developing a partitioning strategy for a multi-tenant application running on DocumentDB.

Since each collection only allows for 10gb of storage I am attempting to calculate how many documents each of my tenants can store, so I can come up with the number of tenants I can place into a collection.

I have a sample Json document that represents a common document that a tenant may store. Using Document Explorer on the Azure Portal does not tell me what the size of one of these documents is on disk (Just a general graph of usage percentage).

I'm also using DocumentDB Studio and am unable to determine the document sizes there. I can use Notepad locally, but depending on my encoding settings (ANSI, , Etc..) I am getting various results.

**My questions are:**

Is there an accurate way to determine the file size a Json file will be stored as within DocumentDB as so that I can properly calculate resource usage of my application?

Is there also a way to get back the size of a document or group of documents via a query against a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you can calculate the size of the document query response, so that all the system properties (e.g. _rid, _ts) are included. You will want to use UTF-8 encoding to get the correct size.

You will also want to factor in an additional ~10% for indexing storage costs.

Comment: Good to know that I can do it. It's still a little unclear to me how. My local OS shows the file sizes as being very large. 6-8kb for a very simple json document. 3-4kb if white space is removed. There is also the size on disk vs file size property... Can I assume that DocDB is using the smaller, compressed version? Would prefer if DocDB could tell me the actual size of the file as it is stored...

Comment: The docs are stored with white-space removed. You can expect 3-4 kb for a doc with ~3,000 - 4,000 characters.

Comment: Ah, so based on this I can store about 3.3 million documents per collection based on a document size average of about 3kb per document. Thanks!