# Get document size in Cosmos DB

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

How can I get or figure out the size of a document stored in Cosmos DB?

Is this something already stored within document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you get (or query) a document, you can then look at the headers that come back, specifically `x-ms-resource-usage`, which will contain a `documentsSize` attribute (representing a document's size in kb).

In node/javascript, you'd make a call that looks something like:

```js
client.readDocument(docLink, function (err, doc, headers) {
  ...
})
```

You'd want to look at `headers['x-ms-resource-usage']`.

Answer (score 17):

Here is the way how to find the largest document in the collection. I used two queries in Azure's data explorer

1. To get the size of the largest document  `SELECT MAX(a.length) FROM ( SELECT LENGTH(ToString(c)) AS length FROM c ) a`
2. To retrieve the body of the largest document (The a.length value should be compared to the length returned from the previous query `SELECT TOP 1 a.c FROM ( SELECT LENGTH(ToString(c)) AS length, c FROM c ) a WHERE a.length = 382725`

Then when running the second query you can peek the Query Stats tab to see the exact size of the document.

Comment: This doesn't work.  It gives a number back, but I'm not sure how it derives it.  The resource usage is correct, but I want to get the max(usage).

Comment: @A.Rowan I found a character length to KB converter online that helped me. That seems to accurately represent the size of the data in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, all the resources created in `azure cosmosdb` will automatically generate the following attributes:

```
_rid

_etag

_ts

_self

id
```

You could find the meaning of these attributes from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-resources).

In addition , the `index strategy` also takes up space in your cosmos db.

I search the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/) for Azure Cosmos DB but didn't find the method get the document size directly.

However, the query in `cosmosdb` consumes `RU` and RU is related to document size. You could refer to the list mentioned in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units).

Please check the `RU` when you search documents on portal.

[image]

You could also refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30175753/determining-size-of-a-json-document-stored-in-documentdb),maybe it has some implications for you.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: which tool are you using in the screenshot?

Comment: @MolteNolte hi, this is the online editor in the azure portal - cosmos db.